# Does malloc() always work to increase the size of an array?

Tags: c++

If I use `malloc()` to increase the size of an array, would that always work, or would I sometimes get a memory error?

Comment: You should use `realloc` if the array was initially allocated with a `malloc`.

Comment: Generally speaking, I wouldn't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Would you also like some advice on inline assembly and instructions on cleaning your CPU fan?

Comment: Well, thank you all for helping me as a beginner. Very friendly.

Comment: @Datoxalas: If you are a beginner at C++, my first and foremost advice would be *not to use `malloc()`*! :-) If you're a beginner at StackOverflow, then my advice would be to ask about your goals, rather than about what you decided to be the first step.

Comment: @Datoxalas: Well, this isn't a help site _per se_...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll "work" if you have enough memory. If you don't have enough memory, then it will not work.

Now, when I say "work", it depends what *you* mean by "work". `malloc` does not increase the size of anything other than your program's memory usage.

Why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! A vector will help me here definitely :-)

Comment: I have another question: In the example on cplusplus.com, they use malloc for dynamically increasing the size of the buffer variable. Should I replace this for a vector?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/

Comment: @Datoxalas, that example isn't _increasing_ the buffer size, it is _creating_ the buffer by dynamically allocating memory. The entire example is pure `C` and not a good example of modern `C++`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: @Datoxalas, it depends on the type of data and whether is has some structure. You can search here on SO for `C++` questions about reading a file into a `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Comment: @Datoxalas: In general, cplusplus.com is full of bad examples like that. Prefer [a decent book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Answer (score 5):

It may be worth mentioning that `malloc` will not increase the size of existing memory.  It allocates new memory.  `realloc` can be used for "increasing" memory, but it is a tricky function at times (it can return a different pointer than the original, and if it fails to allocate new memory the original memory is left unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

[realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) will return `NULL` if it fails to allocate memory.

Malloc won't resize an array. And realloc will only do it for a malloc'd one.